# Need help with the impact of p-value on the performance of systems

Tags: probability, statistics, research

[image: Table 1]

I'm trying to understand the significance of p-value. While scouring through the internet, I came across a question which asked to determine the results between the various groups given in the table. But i am kind of confused and don't know how to solve it. Could someone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I would be confused by that table too

The $p$-value is supposed to be an estimate of the probability of seeing that result or a more extreme result if the null hypothesis is true (presumably in the case of each row of your table, the null hypothesis is that the two groups had the same effect on performance)

Probabilities should be between $0$ and $1$ so you should not have a $p$-value of $2.350$